# Countable / Uncountable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ${A_n}$, n = 1, 2, 3, ... be a sequence of countable sets, and put $B = A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_n \times \cdots$. Show that B is uncountable. Prove that the same statement holds if each $A_n$ = {0, 1}.

I'm not exactly sure how I should begin this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know? Do you already know that every real number can be represented by a sequence of $0$s and $1$s? (AKA a binary representation)

Comment: Have you seen Cantor's diagonalization argument?  I think that is the perfect way to prove this.

Comment: We get into trouble if some of the sets are empty, or if most of them have $1$ element.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for you *countable* means *in bijection with the set of natural numbers*, as each $A_{n}$ is countable, $\vert A_{n}\vert=\vert\mathbb{N}\vert$. Therefore one has

$$\vert B\vert = \vert\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}\vert = \vert\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}\vert =\vert\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\vert\geq\vert 2^{\mathbb{N}}\vert =\vert\mathbb{R}\vert > \vert\mathbb{N}\vert ,$$

where the last equality is due (for example) to the binary representation of real numbers. This chain of inequalities proves both your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B$ is countable, then let $b_n$ enumerate $B$. Define $d$ as follows:

If $b_n(n) = a_n\in A_n$ then pick any $a'_n\in A$ not equal to $a_n$. Then $d(n) = a_n'$.

$d$ must be an element of $B$ as it's $n$th componant is an element of $A_n$, however $d\neq b_n$ for each $n$, as $d$ disagrees with $d_n$ on the $n$th place. Hence $d$ is not in the enumeration of $B$. A contradiction.

Hence $B$ is uncoutable.

Answer (score 0):

$\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\cdots=\{0,1\}^\mathbb N=2^\mathbb N$ is not countable because no function $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow2^\mathbb N$ is surjective because no $n\in\mathbb N$ maps to $M=\{k\in\mathbb N|k\notin f(k)\}$.

$f(n)=M \Rightarrow (n\in M\Leftrightarrow n\notin M)$.